# How to fetch a Parse object and include object references?

Tags: javascript, parse-server

Can a Parse object be fetched with `object.fetch` and at the same time include its object references as in `query.include`?

Here is the query example:

```
let query = new Parse.Query("MyCollection");
query.include("MyObjectReference");
return query.find();
```

How to do it with a fetch command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Parse JS SDK >= 2.0.2

It is possible to fetch one or multiple objects with include:

- `fetchWithInclude` https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/master/Parse.Object.html#fetchWithInclude
- `fetchAllWithInclude` https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/master/Parse.Object.html#.fetchAllWithInclude)

---

### Parse JS SDK < 2.0.2

It's not possible as the [docs](http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#one-to-one-and-one-to-many-relationships) say:

> By default, when fetching an object, related Parse.Objects are not
>   fetched. These objects’ values cannot be retrieved until they have
>   been fetched like so:
>
> ```
> var post = fetchedComment.get("parent");
> post.fetch({
>   success: function(post) {
>     var title = post.get("title");
>   }
> });
> ```

Comment: This is not correct. See fetchWithInclude(). https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/master/Parse.Object.html

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled onto this via a google search and wanted to correct the record. The accepted answer to this is not correct.

You very much CAN do what the OP is asking by using `fetchWithInclude([key1,key2.subkey,key2.subkey2,etc]);`

See: https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/master/Parse.Object.html

Comment: The OP is me and the accepted answer I gave myself was correct until August 2018. I updated my answer, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

A fetch command in Parse is essentially a find with only a "where equal to" on a single object id. So you can simply make a query for a single object id and Parse will handle it like a fetch, e.g. you can restrict a table to only allow fetch and this single object id query will still pass. I haven't read into the code, but I believe that a fetch is essentially a single object id (find) query. You can then also use the include of your find query.